# How to catch Programmatically changed tabBarController setSelectedIndex

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my App i have a situation where i Programmatically change the selected index of a tabBarController like this

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

and go back to my tab containing a UITableView' at this point i need to make some actions on my tableView
i tried to use viewWillAppear and it didn't get there, i tried to make the view delegate like this

```
@interface ThirdViewController : UITableViewController < UISearchBarDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate> 

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
```

it didn't work

any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that your class `ThirdViewController` implements `UITabBarDelegate`, while `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` is in fact a method of [`UITabBarControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3adidSelectViewController%3a) protocol.

Comment: tabBarController:didSelectViewController:is called only with a ui event (click) of the UITabBarController, and i dont have one when using [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];  i tried it but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

or

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Thanks..!

UPDATE :

you can set delegate for tabBarcontroller viewdidLoad method below code:

```
tabBarController.delegate=self;
```

Comment: This is what i did now i want to catch it in the view im jumping to

Comment: I tried your update, it is working if i click on the buttons, but i use the [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; and then the functions not called

Comment: Ok try this method - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{}

Comment: Thank you very much Dinesh for the time and knowledge you put into answering my question but This function is not activated when selected is done programmatically, the solution for me was to make [[controller alloc]init] and activate a function doing the things i need in the controller im moving to

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to make [[controller alloc]init] and activate a function doing the things i need in the controller im moving to

Answer (score 0):

I've made this simple function to select programmatically view controllers inside my UITabBarController.

```
-(void)selectVCfromIndex:(int)index{

    self.selectedIndex = index;
    [self tabBarController:self shouldSelectViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index]];

}
```

In the shoudSelectViewController protocol i have specific code for presenting view controllers and in this way it runs when tabs change both programmatically and by user interaction.